# How to communicate between python server and javascript client using AJAX and Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, server

I am following [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-javascript-communicate-json/) tutorial to communicate between python and javascript. I am a beginner to this so I dont understand what exactly I am doing wrong.

Following is my code in index.html which sends a POST request to the python server side when the button is clicked:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// setup some JSON to use
var cars = [
    { "make":"Porsche", "model":"911S" },
    { "make":"Mercedes-Benz", "model":"220SE" },
    { "make":"Jaguar","model": "Mark VII" }
];
window.onload = function() {
    // setup the button click
    document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
        doWork()
    };
}
function doWork() {
    console.log("posting data")
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.post("receiver", cars, function(){
    });
    // stop link reloading the page
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
This will send data using AJAX to Python:<br /><br />
<button type="button" id="theButton">Click Me!</button>
```

And this is my code on the python side:

```
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, Response
import random, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def output():
    # serve index template
    return render_template('index.html', name='Joe')

@app.route('/receiver', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def worker():
    print("got some data")
    # read json + reply
    data = request.get_json()
    result = ''
    for item in data:
        # loop over every row
        result += str(item['make']) + ''
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

So, when I press the button in the index.html file, the [tutorial](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/python-javascript-communicate-json/) says that I will be able to see a server response in the web browser. But even though my server is running, this is what I see in the network tab of developer tools for index.html in the Firefox web browser:

[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong and how I am supposed to see the communication between the client and server. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not sending JSON, you have to stringify the cars object to send it as JSON.

```
function doWork() {
    console.log("posting data")
    // ajax the JSON to the server
    $.post("receiver", JSON.stringify(cars), function(){
    }, 'application/json');
    // stop link reloading the page
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I also set the content type to `application/json` as this is required by `request.get_json()`.

For your network tab issue, you have `JS` selected so you would not see ajax requests only javascript files. You have to have `XHR` selected or `All`.

Comment: I changed the code to as you recommended, ran the python server again, and then clicked the button in the html page. But I still don't see any changes in the network tab.

Comment: On your network tab do you have `All` or `XHR` selected?

Comment: I have selected "All".